# Set different directives per router-view

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

https://jsfiddle.net/guanzo/8fdbcaxo/2/

The Vue instance has 2  `router-view`'s, `foo` and `bar`. How do i conditionally set directives, based on if the `router-view` is a `foo` or `bar` component? Right now i'm forced to give the same directives to these 2 child components, but what if i want to handle them differently?

Something like this

```
<router-view v-if="isFoo" v-show="showFoo" ></router-view>
<router-view v-else-if="isBar" @click="handleClick" ></router-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have two separate *named* `router-view`s, that way you can attach directives to the specific `router-view` that you want.

[I've updated your fiddle to demonstrate this.](https://jsfiddle.net/8fdbcaxo/4/)

Don't overuse this, though. Think about whose responsibility is should be to handle the click event - `App` or `Bar`? If it's the latter, you might want to put the directive in the Bar component and communicate back to the parent component.